# What are the easiest vegetables & fruits to grow in your apartment?

Tags: vegetables, fruit-trees, indoors, plant-recommendations, fruits

I would like to know what are the easiest and fastest vegetables & fruits that can be grown in a small space with limited sunlight access, like an apartment balcony. I live in the small island of Singapore. It's sunny most of the year with no seasons.

Comment: What part of the world do you live in? Describe how much natural light that your plants would get? How much space do you have?

Comment: Lettuce might do Ok. It's tolerant of less-than-full-sun conditions, and does not need huge amounts of space. Lettuce does not like very hot weather though, so you might have better luck with it in spring or fall.

Comment: @NiallC. i have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: You added one piece of information; I asked for three. The more information that you provide us, the better the answers that you'll get.

Comment: Hi Ameen! Have you seen [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/what-vegetables-will-grow-well-in-limited-sunlight?rq=1) question?  It's not an exact duplicate, but might be related enough to be helpful to you.

Comment: Is there any chance you could set up a grow light? This would expand the list if plants you could grow successfully indoors.

Answer (score 3):

Other than herbs, tomatoes and peppers are probably the easiest to manage in an apartment setting. Strawberries as well, but you won't get great production from strawberries in pots. It's best if you can set these out on an well sunny outdoor patio if you can to improve lighting as well as fruit set from bees.

Comment: My experiences with peppers (on a balcony) is they really need full sun. The OP is talking about limited sun, so I'm not sure the peppers will even grow, let alone fruit. I've never tried strawberries, but I've seen varieties that are intended for small pots. Not sure how much sun they need.

Comment: I read it differently, that the sunlight was limited to basically the balcony.

Comment: @Escoe: It could be. I assumed it was a shaded balcony.

Answer (score 1):

Cut and come again stuff like salad leaves, annual herbs grown in succession e.g coriander parsley. Chives, mint, there's a wide variety of types and 'flavours' e.g. Apple mint. What is expensive in you location and seen if you could grow that easily?